# Scheduled timer good-practices patterns in EJB and plain CDI for an EE app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

I have ear application consisting of war - a servlet and ejb.

I needed the ejb solely for the @javax.ejb.Schedule . Which should have ran every minute and all it would do is fire a CDI event that is going to be intercepted by war app.

It turns out this doesn't work, as, evidently, CDI events only connect when classes share the same class loader. EJB and WAR being different packages - different class loaders.

So i came up with this pattern (in it's most basic form):

```
@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
public class TimerMockUp {

@Resource(mappedName="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/cacheService") Executor ex;
@Inject Event<SomeEvent> evt;

@PostConstruct
private void initTimer(){
    ex.execute(()->{
        try{
            while(true){
                evt.fire(new SomeEvent());
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){

        }
   });
}
```

What is your take on this? Do you think this would be reliable in the long turn? What other options are there to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Just because I am interested as pure ejb-3.x-person. I suppose it is a ejb-3.x application. Why do you need to deploy an ear and can not put everything into a war?

Comment: The initial intention was just to have the WAR only, but the need for the Timer then came to be... which is EJB territory. But then the hickup with the CDI event happened.

Comment: You know, you can put your EJBs into the WAR or are you working with version 2.x? See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gippi/index.html

Comment: Of course you can fire CDI Events from an EJB: https://technology.amis.nl/2013/06/22/java-ee-7-ejb-publishing-cdi-events-that-are-pushed-over-websocket-to-browser-client/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirement is for having injected events, but the standard way for running an incremental timer would be to use an EJB timer with the `@Schedule` annotation.

For example:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class TimerBean {

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/5", persistent = false)
    public void doEvery5Sec() { 
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is true. But this EJB can't send an CDI event to an Observer in another module, which is what i need.